# Optimization of a two dimensional function

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Lets assume we have a two dimensional function

```
def f(x,y): #some calculations here 
    return value
```

we know from observations the following

```
f(x,0.9y) = 10
f(x,0.8y)=15
f(x,0.8y) = 23
```

...

how can I find the right values for x,y to get the best fit to the observations? which procedure is recommended in case of such an optimization problem?

Comment: have a look at PSO - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization

Comment: I don't think this is correctly stated. An observation looks like `f(3,4)=12`. The notation `f(x,0.9y)=10` is rather meaningless.

Comment: why meaningless? we want to find the best x and y that the error to the observations is minimal. if we know one of these parameters it is a simple optimization problem... we can start maybe with two initial guesses

Comment: Understood, but your mathematical notation is nonsensical.

Comment: yes you are right :) do you have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo in your question. Anyhow, given that we only have two data points, *optimization* is not exactly doable, as a set of simultaneous equations gives you an exact result, for many different types of functions.

If you meant to give three data points, there is different approach:
Note that the x is constant. This means that whatever the function is, we cannot say anything about the x portion of the 2D function. So it's really a one dimensional problem: How does y behave?

Given that we know nothing about the data in question, and given the values you gave, I would by gut instinct probably go with an exponential/logarithmic function (assuming the final value is meant to read 0.7). It might also be a linear function, though once you fit a function that you produce, you would have to calculate the error ([here](https://sciencenotes.org/calculate-percent-error/) is how you would do this). Beyond this, in my experience, there is not much that you can do.

Comment: The function depends on two variables. The function itself determines the output (is an integer) over 4 nonlinear ordinary differential equations. I want to choose x and y so that the output matches the observations as good as possible.